# error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to save a part of an image inside a bounding box as follow:

```
digit = thresh[x:x+w,y:y+h]
cv2.imwrite(str(c)+'.png',digit)
```

But I got following error.

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'
```

Need your assistance.

Comment: it can means that you try to save empty array. First check what you have in `digit`. Use `print()` for this. You could also check `x,y,w,h` - maybe `w` and/or `h` is zero.

Comment: A have already plotted the digit, it showing me an image of a digit which I have cropped, but when tried to write it, it shows the error in the question.

Comment: in two line of code and this error I can say only one: `digit` is empty. I don't knwo if you have something more between these two lines but maybe you assign new empty array to `digit` before write. Only you know all your code and only you can use `print()` directly before `imwrite` to check what you have in `digit`

Comment: BTW: if you run `cv2.imwrite('img.png', np.array([]))` then you get the same error - because array is empty. If you add at least one value to array - ie. `np.array([1])` - then it works without error.

Answer (score 1):

That 'x'or 'y' is out of bound of our 'thresh' array
Most of the time it will be in negative value.
Solution would be

```
x=max(0,x)
y=max(0,y)
```